# Print numbers in a range

Tags: ruby

I am trying to print all numbers between 1 and 50, using the following code:

```
[1..50].each{|n|   puts n}
```

but the console print

```
 [1..50]
```

I want to print something like this
1
2
3
4
...
50

Comment: You are using an array above.  You want to specify a range using parentheses.  Here is a helpful link: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Range.html

Comment: `[1..50]` is equivalent to `[(1..50)]` - that should clear it up :D

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
(1..50).each { |n| puts n }
```

The problem is that you're using `[]` delimiter instead of `()` one.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `[1..10]` with a minor tweak:

```
[*1..10].each{ |i| p i }
```

outputs:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

The `*` (AKA "splat") "explodes" the range into its components, which are then used to populate the array. It's similar to writing `(1..10).to_a`.

You can also do:

```
puts [*1..10]
```

to print the same thing.

So, try:

```
[*1..10].join(' ') # => "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10"
```

or:

```
[*1..10] * ' ' # => "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10"
```

To get the output you want.

Comment: You don't need the brackets when using the splat and `puts`. You can do `puts *1..10`.

Answer (score 9):

The error here is that you are creating an Array object with a range as its only element.

```
> [1..10].size
=> 1
```

If you want to call methods like `each` on a range, you have to wrap the range in parentheses to avoid the method being called on the range's last element rather than on the range itself.

```
=> (1..10).each { |i| print i }
12345678910
```

Other ways to achieve the same:

```
(1..50).each { |n| print n }
1.up_to(50) { |n| print n }
50.times { |n| print n }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can cast your range (in parentheses) to an array ([1 2 3 4 5 6... 48 49 50]) and join each item (e.g. with `' '` if you want all items in one line).

```
puts (1..50).to_a.join(' ')
# => 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ... 48 49 50
```